# Kivy: Is there any widget similar to listview that allows to show a column but with another value (code) related to it?

Tags: python, listview, kivy

The problem is simple but I don't know how to solve in Kivy.
    I have some data like: code, name, adress, passport, etc. 
    I like to show only the name (can be repeated) in a widget like listview, but when the name is selected I want to know which code is related to it.

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

I have a workarround with a gridlayout (could be a box but...) here is the code:

```
    while not fin:
        texto = dataSwitch.GetCampo("RCONS", "DIRECCION")
        codigo = dataSwitch.GetCampo("RCONS", "CODIGO")
        label = Label(text = texto)
        label.codigo = codigo
        label.seleccionable = True
        label.seleccionado = False
        self.g_consorcios.add_widget(label)
        if not dataSwitch.MoveCursor("RCONS"):
            fin = True
```

In the Label I have put everything I need, then I need to get the touched label and call a method to do selection in this I call case on_press_algo

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    ret = super(ConsorciosScreen, self).on_touch_down(touch)
    if ret:
        x2, y2 = self.g_consorcios.parent.to_local(touch.x, touch.y)
        for node in self.g_consorcios.children:
            if node.collide_point(x2, y2):
                self.savex = x2
                self.savey = y2
                self.savenode = node
        ret = True
    return ret        
def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    ret = super(ConsorciosScreen, self).on_touch_up(touch);
    if ret:
        for node in self.g_consorcios.children:
            x2, y2 = self.g_consorcios.parent.to_local(touch.x, touch.y)
            if node.collide_point(x2, y2):
                if node == self.savenode:
                    if x2 <= self.savex + 10 and x2 >= self.savex - 10 and y2 <= self.savey + 10 and y2 >= self.savey - 10:
                        self.on_press_algo(node)
        ret = True
    return ret;
```

Finally in on_press_algo I pretend the selection and voila, I have my data in nodo.

```
    if hasattr(nodo, "seleccionable"):
        if nodo.seleccionado:
            nodo.seleccionado = False
            nodo.color = (1,1,1,1)
        else:
            for node in self.g_consorcios.children:
                if hasattr(node, "seleccionable"):
                    node.color = (1,1,1,1)
                    node.seleccionado = False
            nodo.seleccionado = True
            nodo.color = (1,0,0,1)
```